# Error on sign in to traducir.win

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, localization, traducir

We use [traducir.win](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) to translate text for the international Stack Exchange sites, so they get properly localized.

I just tried to sign in to [the Russian traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/) and got the following error:

> [image]

> The exception handler configured on ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response. This InvalidOperationException containing the original exception was thrown since this is often due to a misconfigured ExceptionHandlingPath. If the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses then set AllowStatusCode404Response to true.
> System.InvalidOperationException

Can you look into this so we can continue offering translations for the international Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Not sure who cast that close vote but to the people in the queue: traducir is a tool used for the foreign language SE sites, and questions about it definitely belong here on MSE, as it makes traducir software that powers the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: It's still happening today (tested with pt.traducir.win + google SSO).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Traducir was a victim of some new anti DDoS measures. It's a shame it took me a bit to notice, feel free to ping me on [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal) (or open an issue on [the repo](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues)) if you don't see traction here.