# Error on sign in to traducir.win 2024 edition

Tags: bug, status-completed, regression, traducir

Just got the same error as one and a half year ago on attempt to sign in to [traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/): [Error on sign in to traducir.win](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381034/error-on-sign-in-to-traducir-win)

> [image]

> An error was thrown during this request.
> The exception handler configured on ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response. This InvalidOperationException containing the original exception was thrown since this is often due to a misconfigured ExceptionHandlingPath. If the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses then set AllowStatusCode404Response to true.
> System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Yep, can confirm that I'm able to reproduce this issue. It seems to be happening on all 4 Traducir subdomains.

Comment: They are also tricked by their Cloudlflare anti-bot measures, similar to these reports: https://stackapps.com/questions/10513/stackexchange-oauth2-0-is-suddenly-failing and https://stackapps.com/questions/10497/suddenly-getting-couldnt-parse-client-id and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396674/cloudflare-protection-is-triggering-on-stack-overflow-authentication-api-routes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated so Traducir won't erroneously trigger the bot detection. Everything looks good now. Let me know if you see any more issues.

Comment: What exactly was fixed, and what's the timeline and policy for fixing other broken third-party automations? See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398192/bot-is-unable-to-access-site-from-github-actions